# MultiIndex and columns in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas

When creating a DataFrame with MultiIndex columns it seems not possible to return a single column with a MultiIndex. Instead, an object with an Index is returned:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = np.asarray(pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8))
_metaInfo = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('AA', '[m]'), ('BB', '[m]'), ('CC', '[s]'), ('DD', '[s]')], names=['parameter','unit'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=_metaInfo)
print df.get('AA').columns
# Index([[m]], dtype=object)
```

where the 'parameter' info is missing.
Is this a bug, is there a workaround?

Comment: Do you mean to say it doesn't have a name attribute (of 'AA')?

Comment: No, you loose a lvel of the MultiIndex (in this case the name)

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with this as well. The opposite, adding an extra level to a single (so it matches a MultiIndex), also keeps me busy.

I sometimes use this to keep the index intact:

```
print df.T[[('AA', '[m]') == col for col in df.columns]].T

parameter         AA
unit             [m]
2000-01-01  0.972434
2000-01-02 -0.581852
2000-01-03 -0.784172
2000-01-04 -0.843441
2000-01-05 -1.030200
2000-01-06 -0.864225
2000-01-07 -0.530056
2000-01-08 -0.651367
```

But thats not the most flexible solution when your Index is more complex. In this example it would work.

Comment: There seems to be an inconsistency between MultiIndex rows and MultiIndex columns. Using dates = np.asarray(pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=4))
_metaInfo = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('AA', '[m]'), ('BB', '[m]'), ('CC', '[s]'), ('DD', '[s]')], names=['parameter','unit'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4), index=_metaInfo, columns=dates)

Comment: There seems to be an inconsistency between MultiIndex rows and MultiIndex columns. Using the transpose allows you to select rows as df["AA":"AA"] which then return a MultiIndex DataFrame (not losing information), however, df.xs("AA", axis=1) returns a DataFrmae with a single level Index (thus losing information). In addition to this, when I define a single level (Index) DataFrame with columns AA and BB then df[df["AA"]>0] will give me all the rows of columns AA and BB where the element in AA is greater than 0.0. However, if I do the same in a MultiIndex column DataFrame, then I get a crash.